# Change root password of mysql database

Tags: windows, mysql-5.5

This could be a Rookie problem , but it seems that i am not able to solve it.

I have MySQL server installed on my windows machine(MySQL 5.5) under the Admin username root.
Some How i lost the password of MySQL and want to change it , i m going through [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.5/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html) link in order to solve it.
under c:> mysql-init.txt is :

```
UPDATE MySQL.user SET Password=PASSWORD('root') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

and on command line

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
```

it give an message like **'c:\program' is not recognized as internal or external command.**

So basically i am stuck at point 6 of MySQL documentation. any help ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the path in double quotes "....

Comment: That's the problem with spaces in directory names.  Anytime you want to work with them from the command line, it's a pain.

Comment: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt. this works for me .... thanks